# Marshal a C struct containing a variable length array

Tags: c#, c, arrays, struct, marshalling

I would like to marshal a C struct with a variable-length array back to C# but so far I can't get anything better than a pointer-to-struct representation and a pointer to float.

Unmanaged representation:

```
typedef float        smpl_t;

typedef struct {
  uint_t length;  /**< length of buffer */
  smpl_t *data;   /**< data vector of length ::fvec_t.length */
} fvec_t;
```

Managed representation:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct fvec_t1
{
    public uint length;

    public float* data;
}

[DllImport("libaubio-4.dll", EntryPoint = "new_fvec", PreserveSig = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern unsafe fvec_t1* new_fvec1(uint length);
```

What I would like is to have a .NET style array, where `data` would be `float[]` but if I do change the struct to the form below I do get *Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type*  in the external function above.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct fvec_t1
{
    public uint length;

    public float[] data;
}
```

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5902264/361899), it is not possible to a have a variable-length array marshalled back as-is, is this correct or is it there still a way to achieve this ?

Comment: You can do it easily enough passing an array as a parameter. Any reason why you don't do that? Why are you using `unsafe`?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this ? The thing is when I specify MarshalAs.Struct the call works but the returned struct is garbage (length is incorrect) so I guess it didn't work correctly. So for now, the only thing working is to return a pointer of struct and manually access the items in `data`. About unsafe statement, I've just forgot to remove it.

Comment: You cannot have the array inside a struct and have the marshaller do the work. But you can pass the array as a pointer and get it marshalled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

short answer 
you can't marshal variable length array as an array , because Without knowing the size, the interop marshalling service cannot marshal the array elements

but if you know the size it will be like below:

```
int arr[15]
```

you will be able to marshal it like this:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst=15)] int[] arr
```

if you don't know the length of the array and this is what you want
   you can convert it to intprt and deal with inptr but first you need to create 2 structs

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
struct fvec_t1
{
    public uint whatever;

    public int[] data;
}
```

the other one like below:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
struct fvec_t2{
    public uint whatever;
}
```

create a function to initialize the array like below

```
private static int[] ReturnIntArray()
{
    int [] myInt = new int[30];

    for (int i = 0; i < myInt.length; i++)
    {
        myInt[i] = i + 1;
    }

    return myInt;
}
```

instantiate the first struct

```
fvec_t1 instance = new fvec_t1();
instance.whatever=10;
instance.data= ReturnIntArray();
```

instantiate the second struct

```
fvec_t2 instance1 = new fvec_t2();

instance1.whatever = instance.whatever
```

dynamically allocate space for fvec_t2 struct with extended space for data array

```
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(fvec_t2)) + Instance.data.Length);
```

Transfer the existing field values of fvec_t2 to memory space pointed to by ptr

```
Marshal.StructureToPtr(instance1, ptr, true);
```

Calculate the offset of data array field which should be at the end of an fvec_t2 
struct

```
int offset = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(fvec_t2));
```

get memory address of data array field based on the offset.

```
IntPtr address = new IntPtr(ptr.ToInt32() + offset);
```

copy data to ptr

```
Marshal.Copy(instance.data, 0, address, instance.data.Length);
```

do the call

```
bool success = dllfunction(ptr);

Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
```

Comment: i Read it and i said that you cant  do that :). if you dont like my answe i can delete it

Comment: If I could know the size in advance then I wouldn't have asked the question :-)

Comment: you can convert it to intprt and deal with inptr, and once again you cant use float[] data for the reason i mentioned above . but i really didnt get it why you donw voted my answer :)

Comment: @Aybe check my answer now hope that will help :D

Comment: i didnt test the code i wrote directly their but it should give you an idea how it could be done if you choose to do it this way

Comment: Why do you allocate `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(fvec_t2)) + Instance.data.Length`? `int` type is not 1 byte length.

Answer (score -4):

In the above case I'd definitely use the SizeParamIndex.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct fvec_t1
{
    uint length;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0)] float[] data;
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately, `SizeParamIndex` only works for arrays passed directly as parameters, not for arrays within a struct.  This has to be [done manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22811847/1925996).

Comment: @piedar Really? That's unfortunate, and I'm surprised. According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eshywdt7(v=vs.110).aspx), under "Declaring Prototypes", you ***can*** use `SizeConst` there.