# Marshalling dynamic size array into struct

Tags: c#, struct, pinvoke, marshalling

how can i define a struct with a dynamic sized array?

is it right?

```
struct MyStruc { 

    public int len; 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=0)]
    public int buf[]; 
}
```

Comment: What is 'dynamic sized array'? Array like `List<int>`?

Comment: You will have to make it an `IntPtr` or go `unsafe` (the latter might be easier to get things working correctly).

Comment: i cant use List because in c++ size definition like int*

Comment: It is not dynamically sized, it only ever takes 8 bytes in 32-bit mode.  Surely you meant UnmanagedType.ByValArray?  It is a common trick in C code.

Comment: if i use UnmanagedType.ByValArray, will my code work properly?

Comment: No, `ByValArray` is for inline arrays whose size is known at compile time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Assuming that you want a struct containing a pointer to the array.**

Declare the pointer to the array as `IntPtr` and marshal the array contents manually with `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`, `Marshal.Copy` etc.

**Assuming that you want a variable sized struct rather than a struct containing a pointer to the array.**

You cannot marshal a variable sized struct using p/invoke. You have at least these two options:

1. Break the struct into two parameters.
2. Marshal the struct manually with `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`, `Marshal.Copy` etc.

Comment: Ok i understand but i don't want to work with IntPtr in c# :( but i guess, i haven't got an other way.

Comment: Which of my two assumptions is correct. Showing the C++ declaration of the type would have helped.

Comment: Actually, i'm using a dll and i haven't got dll codes. But i have got dlls' definition of struct. the definition like this: struct MyStruc { 
    int len; 
    int buf[1]; 
}

Comment: But when i talked with developer who is developed this dll, he said to me this buf hasn't got fixed size, it can be dynamicaly.

Comment: I guess, dll side is using pointer to buff and return an array.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I think I follow your logic, but I am having trouble getting it to work, could you provide a sample? THANKS! :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, something like this,       var bulbData = bulb.Bitmap2Bulb(img);
      venusImage.Frame = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bulbData.Length);
      Marshal.Copy(bulbData, 0, venusImage.Frame, bulbData.Length);

Comment: @nagates something like that. In the Q there is a length field that needs marshalling.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Q? (code?) anyways, I tried the above, but my size is still to small, it's 24 when it should be 921616, so clearly I am missing something?

Comment: @nagates You really need to ask a new question

Comment: It would be good if an InterOp-compatible struct could be automatically generated from the closest-match constructor on your actual struct so you could provide struct with the `IntPtr` and array length and do the manual mapping to the corresponding array in that constructor.  I guess the closest alternative is to write a T4 template to generate the InterOp-compatible struct from the variable-sized struct along with the code it needs product the variable-size struct.  Unfortunately that means you end up with two structs for every struct that has an array property on it.