# How can I refactor this unsafe DLL call into one that uses IntPtr in C#

Tags: c#, c, dll, marshalling

I am trying to build an application in .NET for the HackRF One using the library which is written in C...
https://github.com/mossmann/hackrf/blob/master/host/libhackrf/src/hackrf.c

This is the DLL call...

```
[DllImport(dllname)]
public static extern unsafe hackrf_device_list_t* hackrf_device_list();
```

Which returns a pointer to the following object...

```
public struct unsafe hackrf_device_list_t
{
    public byte** serial_numbers;
    public hackrf_usb_board_id* usb_board_ids;
    public int* usb_device_index;
    public int devicecount;
    public void** usb_devices;
    public int usb_devicecount;
};

public enum hackrf_usb_board_id
{
    USB_BOARD_ID_JAWBREAKER = 0x604B,
    USB_BOARD_ID_HACKRF_ONE = 0x6089,
    USB_BOARD_ID_RAD1O = 0xCC15,
    USB_BOARD_ID_INVALID = 0xFFFF,
};
```

I would like to get it into a normal C# managed object. This is how its being used...

```
unsafe public static hackrf_device_info[] HackrfDeviceList() // Enumerates connected hackrf devices
{
    libhackrf.hackrf_device_list_t* ptr = libhackrf.hackrf_device_list();
    //if (ptr == null) throw new Exception("Null pointer returned");
    if (ptr == null) return new hackrf_device_info[0];
    libhackrf.hackrf_device_list_t devs = *ptr;
    hackrf_device_info[] ret = new hackrf_device_info[devs.devicecount];
    for (int i = 0; i < devs.devicecount; i++)
    {
        hackrf_device_info dev = new hackrf_device_info {
            serial_number = PtrToStr(devs.serial_numbers[i]),
            usb_board_id = (hackrf_board)devs.usb_board_ids[i],
            usb_device_index = devs.usb_device_index[i]
        };
        ret[i] = dev;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

This is all from a git repo I found...
https://github.com/makar853/nethackrf

Comment: The problem with the code is you need to allocate the memory for the array being used.  From the first link at top of page : hackrf_device_list_t* list = calloc(1, sizeof(*list));  So I think the alloc function is using Windows Allocate function.  Let me do some research.

Comment: Thanks very much for having a look. This is the first time I've really worked with unmanaged code like this, so I'm a bit in over my head!

Comment: You appear to already have the code to marshal the struct manually, so what is your question, really? If you are wondering whether it would be possible to use `MarshalAs` attributes to make the marshaler do it all for you, then no, your structure contains variable size arrays the size of which is contained in a field in that same structure, which is unfortunately [not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22811701/11683). So keep the code you have. The only thing you need to add is freeing the returned pointer with the freeing function matching its allocating function (should be documented).

Comment: Awesome thanks @GSerg. This has answered my question really. I was trying to understand more about the processes that was going on here and it felt like the code could be written in a more managed fashion. The code feels messy, whatever that means. Not to worry ill bury it deep in the application and never look at it again. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Try following to see if you get a good size.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication169
{
    class Program
    {
        public const string dllname = @"hackrf.dll";
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct hackrf_device_list_t
        {
            public byte[][] serial_numbers;
            public hackrf_usb_board_id usb_board_ids;
            public int usb_device_index;
            public int devicecount;
            public IntPtr usb_devices;
            public int usb_devicecount;
        };
        public enum hackrf_usb_board_id
        {
            USB_BOARD_ID_JAWBREAKER = 0x604B,
            USB_BOARD_ID_HACKRF_ONE = 0x6089,
            USB_BOARD_ID_RAD1O = 0xCC15,
            USB_BOARD_ID_INVALID = 0xFFFF,
        };
        [DllImport(dllname)]
        public static extern IntPtr hackrf_device_list();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr ptr = hackrf_device_list();
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(ptr);

            hackrf_device_list_t hackrf = new hackrf_device_list_t();
            int structuresize = Marshal.SizeOf(hackrf);
        }
    }
  
}
```

Comment: `int size` will always contain `IntPtr.Size` (4 or 8). The struct will not compile because it's not `unsafe`.

Comment: `int size` will always contain `IntPtr.Size` (4 or 8). The struct will compile, but will crash the program due to the arbitrary replacement of pointers with scalars.

Comment: @GSerg : If the data is allocated using the Windows Allocate function than You should get the size of the memory allocated.  I know if you use the window dll you will get the actual size and assume in c# you will also get the size of the memory.

Comment: This is not how it works. `Marshal.SizeOf(ptr)` will return the size of the IntPtr type, which is 4 or 8. `Marshal.SizeOf(hackrf)` will return the size of the unmanaged representation of the `hackrf_device_list_t` *according to your declaration*. It does not attempt, and cannot attempt, to determine the allocated size of the memory pointed to by `hackrf`.

Comment: Given this particular declaration of `public struct hackrf_device_list_t` that you have, running this code will result in a *System.ArgumentException: 'Type 'hackrf_device_list_t' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed.'*