# Marshalling C# byte[] to C++ DLL with DllImport

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, dllimport

I'm experiencing some strange behaviour when marshalling a C# byte[] array to C++.

When the byte[] is passed as an argument I get the expected data in C++. (See ReportData)

When the byte[] is wrapped in a struct I get strange values out. (See ReportBuffer)

What is causing this difference in behaviour and is there anyway to correct it as I need to have the data wrapped in a more complex use case?

**C# Calling Code**

```cs
public struct Buffer
{
    public int DataLength;
    public byte[] Data;
    
    public Buffer(byte[] data) : this()
    {
        Data = data;
        DataLength = data.Length;
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    [DllImport(@"C:\Users\lawsm\source\repos\MarshallingTest\Debug\Test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern void ReportBuffer(Buffer buffer);

    [DllImport(@"C:\Users\lawsm\source\repos\MarshallingTest\Debug\Test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern void ReportData(byte[] data, int dataCount);


    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        Buffer buffer = new Buffer(data);

        Console.WriteLine("Report Buffer");
        ReportBuffer(buffer);

        Console.WriteLine("\n\nReport Data");
        ReportData(data, data.Length);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**C++ Dll Code**

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

struct Buffer
{
public:
    int DataLength;
    uint8_t* Data;  
};


extern "C"
{
    _declspec(dllexport) void ReportBuffer(const Buffer& buffer)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.DataLength; i++)
        {
            std::cout << (int)buffer.Data[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }

    _declspec(dllexport) void ReportData(uint8_t* data, int dataLength)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataLength; i++)
        {
            std::cout << (int)data[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

**Console Output**

```
Report Buffer
1
0
128
0
1
0


Report Data
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong.  The length is the first four bytes.  The order of the length bytes are swapped due to the architecture of the microprocessor.  There is a two byte segment and two byte offset

Comment: Did you try marking your struct with `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]`?

Comment: [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] makes no change

Comment: The length parameter is correct in both cases. The underlying byte[] data is coming out wierd. In the Report Data it correctly comes through as 0-5, in the ReportBuffer it's coming through as 1,0,128,0,1

Comment: What about `Pack` on the `StructLayout` attribute?

Comment: Is this of any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21798986/marshal-a-c-struct-containing-a-variable-length-array

Comment: Wrong declaration, you must use `ref Buffer` to get a Buffer& on the C++ side.

Comment: @MatthewWatson This was really helpful, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I discovered a solution by changing the byte[] array to an IntPtr, allocating the space and copying the data.

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Buffer
{
    public int DataLength;
    public IntPtr Data;
    
    public Buffer(byte[] data) : this()
    {
        Data = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(data.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(data, 0, Data, data.Length);
        DataLength = data.Length;
    }
}

[DllImport("Buffer.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern void ReportBuffer(Buffer buffer);
```

The C++ code remains the same:

```cpp
struct Buffer
{
public:
    int DataLength;
    uint8_t* Data;  
};

extern "C"
{
    _declspec(dllexport) void ReportBuffer(const Buffer& buffer)
    {
        std::cout << buffer.DataLength << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.DataLength; i++)
        {
            std::cout << (int)buffer.Data[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you still need `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]` or the compiler is allowed to hose you in the future. Having worked you what you're asking, my solution is somewhat similar to yours.

Comment: You're very correct, I'll add that to the awnser.

Comment: This is pretty miserable compared to the pattern that passes the length and array as separate parameters.  You now have a memory leak that wasn't there before.

Comment: @BenVoigt: lol I missed it he forgot to free the memory. If I'm not transferring ownership to the native code I'll pin and unpin the array but forgetting to unpin is about as bad.

Comment: @Joshua: Right.  And if you are transferring ownership to the native code, you can't use `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`, you have to use the allocation function matching the deallocation that the native code does later.

Comment: @BenVoigt: If you allocate with `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`, you can free it with `GlobalFree` in native code.

Comment: @Joshua: You can't, because `AllocHGlobal` does not actually allocate or return an `HGLOBAL`.   [When `AllocHGlobal` calls `LocalAlloc`, it passes a `LMEM_FIXED` flag, which causes the allocated memory to be locked in place](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.allochglobal?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @BenVoigt: lol it calls localalloc. Why would they name it that badly?

Comment: @Joshua: I can't help there, but to me that kind of major design flaw justifies (1) never using it and (2) describing all code that does use it as smelly