# c# marshal struct, that has an unknown length array

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, marshalling

I'm working on a project and this came to my mind: I have a struct with an id, and an array inside:

```
struct Str
{
     public uint id;
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
     public byte[] array;
}
```

Then I'd like to allocate it with a random size array:

```
var rnd = new Random();
var str = new Str() { id = 1, array = new byte[rnd.Next(4)] };
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(str);
IntPtr p = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
Marshal.StructureToPtr(str, p, true);
```

The problem is the struct will always be this random, the problem must be with the allocation or something. The last line gives `ArgumentException` when the array size is not 4.

Please help me to find out how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: You should also check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902103/how-do-i-marshal-a-struct-that-contains-a-variable-sized-array-to-c)

Comment: Missed that. So I have to use IntPtr to the array instead of the array itself. Thank you.