# How to convert c++ to c#?

Tags: c#, c++

I not understand what's mean unsigned char field[1];

```
#define FLGX (224)  

struct game {
    unsigned char field_width;
    unsigned char field_height;
    unsigned char field[1]; 
};                       
  
#define GETPOS(g,x,y) (g->field[(g->field_width + 2) * ((y)+1) + ((x)+1)] & (0xff ^ FLGX))
```

Comment: The answer depends on whether you are converting to have it in C# only or to [marshal it to C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5902103/11683) afterwards.

Comment: Looks like a placeholder field used for casting a block of memory that has a much longer `field`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643406/whats-the-need-of-array-with-zero-elements

Comment: Offtopic: this macro looks bad - since it can be easily replaced by function or function template. Additionally it looks like some hack for variable length 2d array, which is in this form definitely UB. See [this cppcon](https://youtu.be/IAdLwUXRUvg?si=yGunVgJuAMM6jhvP&t=884).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to translate languages line by line is a bad idea. Conceptually this struct just holds a width and height along with a char array of size `width * height`. The GETPOS macro indexes into that char array and masks off some bits used for bookkeeping. In C# you can just have a `char[]`.